# How can I avoid nested loops for maximum efficiency?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, for-loop, nested-loops

I wrote this iterate through a series of facebook user likes.  The scrubbing process requires the code first pick a user, then pick a like, then a character from that like.  If too many characters in a like are not english characters (in the alphanum string) then the like is assumed to be gibberish and is removed.

This filtering process continues through all likes and all users.  I know having nested loops is a no no, but I don't see a way to do this without having a triple nested loop.  Any suggestions?  Additionally if anyone has any other efficiency or conventional advice I would love to hear it.

```
def cleaner(likes_path):   
'''
estimated run time for 170k users: 3min
this method takes a given csv format datasheet of noisy facebook likes.
data is scrubbed row by row (meaning user by user) removing 'likes' that are not useful
data is parsed into manageable size specified files.
if more data is continuously added method will just keep adding new files
if more data is added at a later time choosing a new folder to put it in would
work best so that the update method can add it to existing counts instead
of starting over
'''
with open(os.path.join(likes_path)) as likes:
    dct = [0]
    file_num = 0
    #initializes naming scheme for self-numbering files
    file_size = 30000
    #sets file size to 30000 userId's
    alphanum = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 $%@-'
    user_count = 0
    too_big = 1000
    too_long = 30
    for rows in likes: 
        repeat_check = []        
        user_count += 1
        user_likes = make_like_list(rows)   
        to_check = user_likes[1:]       
        if len(to_check) < too_big:
            #users with more than 1000 likestake up much more resources/time 
            #and are of less analytical value          
            for like in to_check:      
                if len(like) > too_long or len(like) == 0:
                    #This changes the filter sensitivity.  Most useful likes 
                    #are under 30 char long
                    user_likes.remove(like)
                else:
                    letter_check = sum(1 for letter in like[:5] if letter in alphanum)                                          
                    if letter_check < len(like[:5])-1:
                        user_likes.remove(like)                     
            if len(user_likes) > 1 and len(user_likes[0]) == 32:
               #userID's are 32 char long, this filters out some mistakes
               #filters out users with no likes            
                scrubbed_to_check = user_likes[1:]
                for like in scrubbed_to_check:
                    if like == 'Facebook' or like == 'YouTube':
                        #youtube and facebook are very common likes but 
                        #aren't very useful
                        user_likes.remove(like)
                    #removes duplicate likes
                    elif like not in repeat_check:
                        repeat_check.append(like)
                    else:
                        user_likes.remove(like)                                    
                scrubbed_rows = '"'+'","'.join(user_likes)+'"\n'                
                if user_count%file_size == 1:
                    #This block allows for data to be parsed into
                    #multiple smaller files
                    file_num += 1
                    dct.append(file_num)
                    dct[file_num] = open(file_write_path + str(file_num) +'.csv', 'w')
                    if file_num != 1:
                        dct[file_num-1].close()
                dct[file_num].writelines(scrubbed_rows)    
            if user_counter(user_count, 'Users Scrubbed:', 200000):
                break
print 'Total Users Scrubbed:', user_count
```

Comment: you could wrap your logic into functions and do a nested comprehension.

Comment: One obvious optimization is replacing alphanum with: alphanum = set('...'). Currently alphanum is string so 'if letter in alphanum' requires iteration within string. For set it will be constant time.